# Display blank on formula error

Tags: error, numbers, time

I'm making a timesheet.
I have `=sum (A2-A1)` but I have more than one task a day and not all times are used. The cells without time in them result in an error with the formula. Which, in turn, choses the day totals to show an error also.

[image: Time Tracker]

How can I show a blank cell instead of the error?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `IFERROR()` function.

`IFERROR(SUM(A2-A1),"")`

If the cell calculation is valid, the calculation is displayed.  If there is an error in the cell, then this just returns "". (blank)